# Git pull/push с локального сервера на хостинг git ssh

Tags: git-push

Могу ли я через `ssh` получить доступ к содержимому папки паблик `HTML`, добавить гит репозиторий, сделать `pull` содержимого в папку мампа и потом уже коммитить с локалки, отслеживая лишь файлы стилей и шрифтов, дорабатывая уже боевую версию сайта?

> Хостинг: timeweb (у меня не вышло почему-то подключиться через ssh,
>   не смотря на то, что я добавил пользователя в настройках хостинга
>   (смог подключиться через фтп клиент))

Comment: если не можете подключиться (по этому поводу лучше всего обратиться в соответствующую техподдержку), значит не можете и получить доступ.

Comment: Опубликуйте репозиторий, к примеру, на битбакете пульте и пуште на него.